# Can I have multiple web project in single website

Tags: .net, iis, deployment, web-deployment

I have created one web application and now requirements keep coming and it is growing day by day. I deploy application by publishing it. Now since application is having many modules I don't want to take risk of publishing entire web application even if there is small change in one module. I was planning to separate out each module as single web application and publish only those which are modified.

I was wondering if I can have multiple projects in same website in IIS or I can go for different alternative?

If SO is not a good place for such theoretical question then please suggest right place in comment :)

Comment: Unless your experiments show a more specific issue, there isn't much to discuss.

Comment: As far as I know, if you use visual studio deploy the web application to IIS, it will just deploy modified file.  Besides, we could add multiple web project in single websites in IIS. We could directly add the web site as sub websites by using right click panel.

Answer (score 0):

The requirement in IIS according to the documenation is that a site must have at least one application (this is called the root or default application). However, a site can have more than one application if one wants to.

So Yes, you can have multiple projects in the same site in IIS. Keep in mind that there may be downsides to this approach depending on your needs/applications.

p.s It looks to me as if you want to pass from a monolithic architecture to a new one. There are better solutions if this is the case.

Comment: Can you pls mention better solutions? How can I cofigure IIS to support multiple web apps?

Comment: Well, you can just publish the apps under folders in the your site root folder. Then, open IIS Manager, go to your site and find the folders you just published. Right click each folder and choose "convert to application". Depending on your needs you may need to create seperate application pools for each application or you may use the same for all of them. You can choose the application pool for each app after you click "convert to application". Applications can then be accessed as yoursite.com/app1, yoursite.com/app2.

Comment: Better solutions depend on your needs. There are downsides to having related modules/apps under the same IIS site (but they may not affect anything in your case). If you want and have the time you can go with a microservice based approach for different parts of your application. But again, maybe just different apps under one site may just be suitable for your requirements.